# How do I go about making an inline Jquery Autocomplete that is triggered by a certain character entry & searches for a modified ui.term

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a textarea in which I write notes. When I enter a certain character, for example "@" I want to create an inline Jquery autocomplete which searches for a term matching the characters after the "@".

An example of the textarea input might be:

Please call @John Citizen regarding his order.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not certainly not *that* simple, but here's how I would *approach* this problem.

First of all, take a very good look at the [jQuery UI autocomplete plugin's documentations page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). The solution here would be a combination of those.

You'll want to store the last character entered by the user in a variable, then check on [`autocompletesearch`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-search) to see if the characters the user is currently entering is after an `@` and before another whitespace character, and canceling the search by returning false if the condition is not met.

Next the `source` for the autocomplete will need to be a custom callback that processes the current content of the `textarea` for what the user has already typed after the `@` and search through your array for matches to that name.

Finally, the `autocompleteselect` event will need to be modified to insert in the names in the correct positions after the user has chosen the name. The `autocompletefocus` event will also have to be suppressed for this to work. You'll want to have a look at the Multiple Tags and the combobox examples for this.